# Span With Block Property On Responsive Email

Tags: html, css, email

I'm building a responsive template for my company and referencing a PSD as the basis of the template.

The designers are very picky about spacing (naturally).

I'm trying to find a way to control spacing in an area where line-height isn't cutting it.

I'm trying to control the spacing between a subhead and the body copy below it. A 
 is not enough and 2 of those are too much. There's also an image left aligned to the left of the copy.

My thought was this:

```
<span style="display:block; height:10px;">&nbsp;</span>
```

What are your thoughts on the above solution? Think it'll pass the Outlook test?

Here's [the code in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frankDraws/55nkc0t3/).

Comment: Why not use `margin` or `padding`? Never use `&nbsp;` for spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-bottom` property with px or em value.
E.g: `padding-bottom: 20px;`

So, Here is updated code with space between header text and body.

```
<span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 30px; color: #254271; text-align:left; line-height:30px; display:block; letter-spacing:-1px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase; **padding-bottom: 45px;**">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</span><br />
```

**Full update:**

http://jsfiddle.net/55nkc0t3/1/